# Youtube Channel Gallery getting no longer supported video from YouTube

Tags: youtube, wordpress

Suddenly the feed on our homepage has the - This device is no longer supported - video from YouTube. Everyone is seeing this no matter what device they are on, so we think it doesn't like something about the plugin now after YouTube changed and knew they would not be seen on certain devices and televisions: https://youtube.com/devicesupport

What is the fix for this? Are you pushing out an update to address this? Thanks.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-channel-gallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a read through this thread in the support forum for the plugin:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-no-longer-supported-video-from-youtube

There are some different solutions, depending on whether you are using the widget or shortcode, but a few different approaches came up depending on what is easiest for you - personally, I favor this one:

> - open the file wp-content/plugins/youtube-channel-gallery.php
> - goto line 622 and paste this (directly under the foreach-line): if ($entry->title == 'https://youtube.com/devicesupport') { continue; }
> - let the plugin display 1 more video than before (maxitems)
>
> What it does is: just throws away the "device support" video from the video feed. so there's one video less now, this is why you have to add 1 to the maxitems.

*Credit goes to Wordpress.org forums member "koem"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for the youtube videos and I fixed as follows:

After the installation of the youtube plugin in our site, we can see that the folder with the file name youtube-feeder.php

There is a function named "getFeedUrl" and this function is calling from the function

So the line is:
$dataURL ="To get the above URL please follow the below step";

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list

put the part as contentDetails and forUsername as [channel id] eg:Google
then execute then find the "uploads": "UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA" from the list (ID will be different for your channel)

then go to the following:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list

Then put the part as snippet and paste the copied uploads id in the playlistId then execute. you can see the result and you just copy the Request URL from the result.

Note: you need to register your application for API_KEY

developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Second:

You need to change the parsing section also:

OLD code:

```
$entries = array();
if($data && is_array($data['feed']['entry']))
                               {
                                       foreach($data['feed']['entry'] as $vid)
                                       {
                                               $vid = $vid['media$group'];
                                               $url = $vid['media$content'][0]['url'];
                                               $url = substr($url, 0, stripos($url, '?'));
                                               $entries[] = array(
                                                               'id' => $vid['yt$videoid']['$t'],
                                                               'url' => $url,
                                                               'title' => $vid['media$title']['$t'],
                                                               'date' => $vid['yt$uploaded']['$t'],
                                                               'content' => $vid['media$description']['$t']
                                                       );
                                       }
                               }
```

New Modification:

```
$entries = array();
                               if($data && is_array($data['items']))
                               {
                                       foreach($data['items'] as $vid)
                                       {
                                       //var_dump($data['items']);
                                               $vid = $vid['snippet'];
                                               $url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+$vid['resourceId']['videoId'];
                                               //$url = substr($url, 0, stripos($url, '?'));
                                               $entries[] = array(
                                                               'id' => $vid['resourceId']['videoId'],
                                                               'url' => $url,
                                                               'title' => $vid['title'],
                                                               'date' => $vid['publishedAt'],
                                                               'content' => $vid['description']
                                                       );
                                       }
                               }
```

Then check it out, If its not coming the exact data, please comment the following line also.

```
`if(!$entries = $this->getCachedYoutubeData($id, $cache, $type, $orderby))`
```

Please write here if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API 3 is very different from API 2. I just switched plugins - wpyoutubevideogallery.com - easy to setup and fully functional with youtube API 3. Also free.